# Linux Chromium: Enable Emacs Style Key Bindings

Tags: linux, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, chromium

I'm running Chromium on Linux (Without Gnome) and I'm trying to figure out how to enable emacs style keybindings. For example, if I'm editing text in a text area, I want <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> to move the cursor to the beginning of the line, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> to move to the end. Right now, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> selects all the text, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> tries to do a google search.

I've tried the suggestions from [Jeff Kaufman](https://www.jefftk.com/p/emacs-keybindings-in-chrome-without-gnome), [Tibor's Musings](http://tiborsimko.org/emacs-bindings-in-gtk-apps.html), but nothing has worked. Does anyone know how to enable emacs style key bindings in Chromium on Linux?

Answer (score 5):

I think I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/918962). It looks like chromium just switched to gtk3 in version 59, so the key theme had to be set in the gtk3 config instead of the gtk2 config as before.